# Mailchimp cart content block

Tags: mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I am creating a website with mailchimp integration using their API. I am using their drag and drop cart block content feature, it seems that the price that is reflected in that block is not the price of the cart but the price of the product.

My first solution is to get the price using a cart merge tag, I have been searching for merge tags but cant find any website that provides me this merge tags.

I would like to use the cart price instead, does anyone knows how can I put the cart price? I've been looking for solution for this problem all day. I hope one of you can help me.

Thank you.

Check this video as well
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nTi4nU8ZOj0

Answer (score 2):

You can use the merge tag `ABANDONED_CART` to create custom html for abandoned cart emails.

Example:

```
<table>
    *|ABANDONED_CART:[$total=3]|*
    <tr>
        <td><img src="*|PRODUCT:IMAGE_URL|*"/></td>
        <td>*|PRODUCT:TITLE|*</td>
        <td>*|PRODUCT:PRICE|*</td>
    </tr>
    *|END:ABANDONED_CART|*
</table>
<a href="*|CART:URL|*">Go to Cart</a>
```

The $total=3 in the `ABANDONED_CART` tag changes the number of products that will be shown.

`*|CART:URL|*` - Generates the url for your cart.

Comment: Do you have a list of the available vars for product?

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't seem possible. Here's a very recent [list of available tags from mailchimp](http://kb.mailchimp.com/merge-tags/all-the-merge-tags-cheat-sheet) . There's no `CART` block or `CART_PRICE` tag.

I contacted mailchimp support with a similar query.

ME:

> I'd like to customize the contents of the cart
>   block. The test emails/ abandoned carts I have created use the
>   `checkout_url` as the product image link within the template. Is it
>   possible to have the cart block product image link url set to that of
>   the product or the product link variant?
>
> If that is not possible is there an equivalent PRODUCT_CART tag to
>   `PRODUCT_RECOMMENDATIONS` as documented here
>   http://kb.mailchimp.com/merge-tags/all-the-merge-tags-cheat-sheet#Merge-Tags-for-Product-Recommendations
>   that I could use to construct my own abandoned cart email, not using the
>   predefined cart block drag and drop content block.
>
> In summary:
>
> 1) Within the cart block is it possible to have the product images link
>   to the products and not the `checkout_url`?
>
> 2) Is there a tag not listed in
>   http://kb.mailchimp.com/merge-tags/all-the-merge-tags-cheat-sheet to
>   iterate over cart products?

SUPPORT:

> There is not a way to change the URL linked to the product image. Additionally, those products must be pulled in using the abandoned cart content blocks, and cannot be populated using a merge tag.
>
> That being said, I do agree these would be great options to have, and I would be happy to pass that feedback along for you. Our developers monitor these suggestions and often use that feedback for future versions of the application. So thank you for giving us your idea, as it may be very useful for a lot of our users in the future.
>   Let us know if you have any other questions on this, and have a great rest of your day.